# Ajax Call with PUT method

Tags: ajax, json

i am trying to make ajax call with PUT method. Below is the code, but i am getting with the error **XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{c847a4af-f009-4907-a103-50874fcbbe35} Line Number 1, Column 1:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            async: true,
            url: "http://localhost:8080/karthick/update",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
           contentType: "application/json",
           dataType: "JSON",
           processdata: true,
           success: function (json) {  //On Successfull service call

               },
               error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
               }
           });


           return false;
       };





   function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
       alert(xhr.responseText);
       if (xhr.responseText) {
           var err = xhr.responseText;
           if (err)
               error(err);
           else
               error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
       }
       return;
   }
```

But this service is working Good with Rest-client jar. Also my POST method works fine in my browser. Please help me in this.

Regards 
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error comes, when making a cross browser request.  Try data: JSONP and see if it helps.